# How to update 'Mai' (in french) to 'mai' inside a date field value (Drupal, Multilingual)

Tags: drupal, internationalization, multilingual

In my Drupal 7 site:

THere is one view block which displays title and date (say meeting_date).

When i switch to French language for the site, the date for (May 2014) is displayed as (Mai 2014), I want the French language for the site to display (mai 2014).

I have checked various Language specific configuration settings. But no luck.

Needed a way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had installed all the multilingual-internationalization modules, you can go to `admin/config/regional/translate/translate`, and search for "May" (en) and you can translate yourself to "mai" (fr).